# How to fit two divs side by side horizontally?

Tags: css, layout, html

How to sit two divs side by side horizontally using css, where the direction of the container DIV is from right to left ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div style="float:right;">
    Right div
</div>
<div>
    Left div
</div>
```

Comment: Does the right div have to go first? Intuitively, I'd list left div first and then the right div.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="width:960px;overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="float:right;width:600px;overflow:hidden;">
     //right DIV
  </div>
  <div style="float:right;width:360px;overflow:hidden;">
     //left DIV
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanatory text to your example.