# getting two divs to display side-by-side

Tags: html, css

How do I get the two images contained within the two divs to display side-by-side? **I've tried changing the variables within `container` as `display: inline-block;` and `float: left;` as suggested by some other threads, but those did not work the way I tried them.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Slide in Overlay from the Bottom</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How it looks:

[image]

I want these to be displayed side-by-side, not on top of one-another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fit two divs side by side horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616663/how-to-fit-two-divs-side-by-side-horizontally) and a multitude of same answers found by searching SO.

Comment: I asked this because -- as I indicate in my question details above -- I have seen the answers to previously-asked issues of the same nature, and the answers to those did not work for me...

Comment: Funny you accepted the answer that is the same as the one I linked to, and many others found on SO, but you claim none of them worked.

Comment: yes, the answers to that question said `float: right;` was the solution. Indeed, I tried `float: right;` The answer to my solution was not `float:right`, it was `float: left;`. I come here because if someone says `float: right` is the solution, I'm gonna put `float: right.`

Comment: How about u simply set your `.container` to `display: flex`? I always try to avoid floats.

Comment: Indeed, I was (and still am) misunderstanding the concept. If everyone who answers SO questions thinks like you do, they will include "why" as part of their response. As you can see in the answers of the question you linked to, as well as mine, nobody gives a shit to tell me or anyone else "why." They just say 'add this' ... done. Now who's fault is that? I'm just trying to fix my problem, and it's discouraging to get down-votes and close-requests for asking questions meant for this platform.

Comment: @FabioVella I did just now, and it stretched the image out :( (and they are not aligned next to one-another)

Comment: Oh I see! My bad, you need to add display flex to a parent of the two `.container` divs. that way you will get the two next to each others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrap the two containers in a div set to `display: flex` you'll be fine.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- your content -->
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- your content -->
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: That worked too, and actually, I preferred it because the `float: left;` did not allow me to place more than 2 divs next to each other comfortably and in centered format. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah.. stay away from floats 

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `float:left` to the container class.

Result:

[image]